# R package failing R CMD Check due to non standard expressions inside dplyr function arguments

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```r
    data.frame(a=1:20) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(x = ifelse(a <= 10 & a > 0, 10, a)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(y = unlist(x) / sum(unlist(x)))
```

In the above code, `rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck()` is complaining that there is no global binding for `a` and `x`.

Is the below the only solution?
Is it worth doing this:

```r
    data.frame(a=1:20) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(x = {
      a <- get("a", envir=environment())
      ifelse(a <= 10 & a > 0, 10, a)}) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(y = {
      x <- get("x", envir=environment())
      unlist(x) / sum(unlist(x))})
```

Comment: Add this somewhere in one of your package `.R` files (*not* within a function): `utils::globalVariables(c("a","x"))`.

Comment: I think the recommended way to do this now is use `.data$a` rather than `a` and then import the `.data` pronoun from `dplyr`

Comment: Is that good practice? `a` and `x` are not global variables? What will that function do to the global namespace?

Comment: From its help page: *"For 'globalVariables', the names supplied are of functions or other objects that should be regarded as defined globally when the 'check' tool is applied to this package."* So I believe that they are not added to the global namespace with the actual package, just assumed to be there for the sake of the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways to mitigate this:

1. Add `utils::globalVariables(c("a","x"))` somewhere within your package's `.R` files. Not within a function, this call needs to happen when the files are sourced (e.g., during checks).

Or referencing https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#eliminating-r-cmd-check-notes-1,

2. use `.data$`:

   ```r
   data.frame(a=1:20) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(x = ifelse(.data$a <= 10 & .data$a > 0, 10, a)) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(y = unlist(x) / sum(unlist(x)))
   ```

   (You may need `.data$x` as well.)

   **Edit:** @MrFlick [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63878156/ggplot2-aes-vs-aes-string#comment112957247_63878156) that this will require importing the `.data` pronoun from `dplyr` or `ggplot2`.
3. use `{{..}}` semantics:

   ```r
   x_ <- "x"
   data.frame(a=1:20) %>%
     dplyr::mutate({{x_}} := ifelse(a <= 10 & a > 0, 10, a)) %>%
     dplyr::mutate(y = unlist(x) / sum(unlist(x)))
   ```

   (You may need `unlist({{x_}})` as well ...)