# ggplot2, aes vs aes_string

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

So I need to replace `aes` with `aes_string` due to failing `rcmdcheck()`.

Original:

```r
        aes(
          x = A,
          y = pmax(B, C, na.rm = TRUE),
          ),
```

My confusion is regarding `B` and `C`. Am I allowed to put quotes around them since they are inside the `pmax` function? Like so:

```r
        aes_string(
          x = "A",
          y = pmax("B", "C", na.rm = TRUE),
          ),
```

Is the below yet another solution?:

```r
        aes(
          x = .data$A,
          y = pmax(.data$B, .data$C, na.rm = TRUE),
          ),
```

EDITED:

The R CMD Check error is that there is no global binding for the variables `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Comment: The `.data$` solution is recommended for packages. You just need to import the `.data` pronoun from `ggplot2` (or `dplyr`) `aes_string` is deprecated and should be avoided for future code.

Comment: Probably the safest way here would be to create a column that equals your `pmax()` function in the dataset, then define that column name via `aes_string()` as you would normally.  `df$mycol <- pmax(B, C, na.rm = TRUE)` and then `aes_string(x="A", y="mycol")` within your `ggplot()` call should work.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `aes` and `aes_string` is very simply, that `aes_string` will interpret the string that is describing the arguments. Eg. the following works

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(aes_string(x = "log(hp)", y = "1/log(mpg)", col = "factor(cyl)"), data = mtcars) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(col = 'cyl')
```

This is also documented on the `help(aes_string)` page

> aes_ and aes_string require you to explicitly quote the inputs either with "" for aes_string(), or with quote or ~ for aes_().

But as MrFlick stated in the comments, these functions are all soft-deprecated, which I believe means that they are kept for compatibility but usage is discouraged.

## Edit:

As noted by MikeRSpencer in the comments, the recommended method is to use `.data[[var]]`. Thereby the above example should've been

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
ggplot(aes(x = log(.data[["hp"]]), y = 1/log(.data[["mpg"]]), col = factor(.data[["cyl"]])), data = mtcars) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(col = 'cyl')
```

Comment: As Oliver notes, `aes_` is deprecated. The docs page recommends using `.data[[var]]` to point to your variable instead: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html